# continous speech recocnition end point detection

Tags: algorithm, matlab, speech-recognition, endpoint

does somebody know the algorithm for end point detection in continuous speech? because I can't find one, the existing algorithm is for isolated word, and not continuous, plis help. If may matlab source code would be helpfull

this is my algorithm

```
index1=[];
for i=1:length(spektral)
if abs(spektral(i))> 0.025
    y(i)=spektral(i);
    index1=[index1 i];
else y(i)=0;
end
end



spasi=[];
for i=2:length(index1)-1
if index1(i)>(index1(i-1)+1)
    spasi=[spasi ; index1(i-1) index1(i)];     %penentuan spasi antarkata
end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are not here to write your code. Please add a [mcve] detailing the code you have tried, list the errors, if any, explain why it does not work for you and what you expect it to do.

Comment: sorry I'm new here, I said if may, if not, can you show me the robust algorithm of end point detection on continuous speech recognition, because my algorithm always can't get the right word, by the way i'm making my own algorithm using my own threshold, and trying the treshold one by one, so an algorithm maybe helpfull

Comment: Add that algorithm you created to the question and point out why it does not work for you and add the expected result.

Comment: index1=[];
for i=1:length(spektral)
    if abs(spektral(i))> 0.025
        y(i)=spektral(i);
        index1=[index1 i];
    else y(i)=0;
    end
end



spasi=[];
for i=2:length(index1)-1
    if index1(i)>(index1(i-1)+4)
        spasi=[spasi ; index1(i-1) index1(i)];     %space deciding
    end
end



that's my algorithm, spectral is the energy produced, i use my own threshold see 0.0025 over there? it's threshold for what is voice and what is unvoice, and see +4 on second loop, i'm deciding that if the unvoiced consist of 4 segments or more then it is a space,

Comment: sorry im new, that's my algorithm, spectral is the energy produced, i use my own threshold see 0.0025 over there? it's threshold for what is voice and what is unvoice, and see +4 on second loop, i'm deciding that if the unvoiced consist of 4 segments or more then it is a space

Answer (score 0):

The first loop can be omitted completely:

```
[row,col,val] = find(spektral>0.025);
```

This will output `val` the same as you have defined `y` above. Depending on the size of `spektral`, either `row` or `col` will contain your `index1`. If `spektral` is a column vector it will be `row`, if `spektral` is a row vector it will be `col`.

The second loop you can omit as well:

```
[row,col,val] = find(index1(2:end,:)>index1(1:end-1,:)+1);
```

Note that `index1` will have to be either `row` or `col` as output from the first [`find`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) command.

If I understand correctly, you want to have the spectral energy *below* the threshold to be considered as noise and want to have more than four seconds of this spectral energy below the threshold to classify it as a silence. In that case:

```
[row,col,val] = find(spektral<0.025);
tmp = cummin(row); % use cummin(col) if spektral is a row vector
```

Here I always struggle with find a short, vectorised way to check to subsequent amount of ones in the column, I'll add it when I find the solution.

You can do this with a nested while loop, but there's bound to be a vectorised way:

```
kk = 1;
while kk<length(tmp)-1
    silence1 = 0;
    while tmp(kk) = tmp(kk+1)
        silence1 = silence1+1; % Sum the length of each silence
        kk = kk+1;
    end
silence(kk) = silence1;
end
silence(silence1==0)=[]; % Remove zero entries
TotalSilences = (sum(silence>4)); % Find the total number of silences
```